# Can the gradient norm (during gradient-based optimization) be saved with a recorder?

Tags: openmdao

is it possible to save the gradient-norm used by the optimizer as the convergence criteria using a recorder for later visualization? I'm thinking back to MDO class homework assignments where we would plot the gradient norm over the major iterations (see example below. sorry, it's not the prettiest graph and probably should have been in log scale). Having that ability would be useful for presenting optimization results.

[128D Rosenbrock Optimality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7xGO.png)

I use both the SciPy and PyOptSparse optimizers. I've tried to find something in the docs, but no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [`record_derivatives`](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.17.0/features/recording/case_recording_options.html) option on the drivers's [`recording_options`](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.17.0/features/recording/driver_recording.html). It's turned off by default, but turning it on will cause every call to the derivatives to be saved into the case database.
Once it is in the database, you can retrieve it by checking the [`derivatives`](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.17.0/features/recording/case_reader_data.html#getting-derivative-data-from-a-case) attribute of the case object.

It can be helpful to look at the derivative data, including plotting its norm'd value. However, please keep in mind that this norm is only expected to go to zero for unconstrained optimizations. For constrained optimizations (both inequality and equality constraints) you are minimizing the derivative of the [lagragian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). This includes the objective gradient, but also terms from all the constraint gradients and the lagrange multipliers as well. So you can't always expect the norm of the objective gradient by itself to go to zero.

Comment: sorry, I was referring to the norm of the langrangian gradients. Is there a way to get this from the drivers?

Comment: This data is not currently returned during iterations to OpenMDAO by any of the optimizers I know of in scipy or pyoptsparse as of OpenMDAO V3.18. They tend to write that data out into some kind of an optimization history file, which can be parsed. But its not recorded by OpenMDAO (again, because its not reported in memory to OpenMDAO in any form)